Is The Revelation the earliest Christianity?
Recently, I read The Revelation and came to the following interpretive conclusions:

The opening three chapters are about seven churches in Greece, i.e., in current Western Turkey. History abundantly informs us this part of the world was heavily populated by Hellenic Jews. Regarding the seven churches, my impression is there is one group of Jews here being persecuted by another group of Jews; thus labelling the persecuting jews "false Jews of the Synagogue of Satan".

While 2 Kings 17:23 literally says God banished Israel from his sight, never to return; and while only the two tribes of Judah & Benjamin remained in their non-Israel kingdom of Judea; the Revelation refers to 12,000 of each of the Twelve Tribes that will be saved and how there will be 12 trees for the healing of the nations; culminating in a New Jerusalem.

The translation 'Gentile' I read only once; however it & the translation of "the nations" are used in a manner that gave the impression of exclusively Jewish thought. In other words, the Gentiles appear not yet part of this new religion. For example, Paul's notion/sentiment that under Christ there is no Jew & no Gentile appears completely absent from The Revelation. Similarly, universalist sentiments such as in Luke's Parable of the Good Samaritan appear absent. My salient impression is The Revelation is an exclusively Jewish text in terms of thought or belief (despite I guess it written in Greek); composed in the same style as Old Testament prophecy.


Are there linguistic clues to support or otherwise disprove my impression that The Revelation represents the most early primitive writings of 'The Way'?

If I understand your question correctly, this is essentially asking  - Was Revelation written before or after the earliest writings of Paul and the gospels?  The current consensus is that Revelation was written about 90 AD and the earliest parts of Paul's writings were about 45 AD.  Indeed, 1 Cor 15:1-8 contains what appears to be either an early creed or a hymn about Christ.  The writings contained in Rev 1, 2, & 3 appear to be a more developed form of maturing (and in some places souring) Christianity.  Rebuke for heresies takes more time to develop.

The word for "gentile" is ἔθνος (ethnos) occurs 23 times in Revelation but only once in Rev 1-3 (2:26), but versions most render this instance "nations" as with the other 22 times.  Therefore, please clarify your question.

Thank you. This does not change my question.

uestions which focus on a self-made biblical topic are liable to be closed. This uestion is not enquiring about a specific text of scripture, to analye and discover its meaning. This question is analysing its own theory.

The early Church still considered itself a part of Judaism, not as a separate religion.
The Book of Revelation contains expressions like "them of the synagogue of Satan, which say they are Jews, and are not".
Here, it is the Christians in Philadelphia that are being addressed and are being compared with other congregations that have fallen away from the truth.
John is likely using the term "Jew" to mean one of God's true followers, just as he uses "synagogue" to mean what today we would call a church building (which we now abbreviate to "church", even though that word refers to the people, not to the building).
If he were writing it today, it would be more like "them of the church of Satan, which say they are Christians, and are not".
The idea that "Paul's notion/sentiment that under Christ there is no Jew & no Gentile appears completely absent from The Revelation" is not true.
In fact, by the time that Revelation was written (after the other scriptures), the racial Jew/Gentile distinction has been fully abandoned and transformed into a spiritual distinction between Christians and non-Christians.
We can see similar usage where Christians are referred to as "the Israel of God" in Galatians 6:15–16:

For in Christ Jesus neither circumcision availeth any thing, nor uncircumcision, but a new creature.
And as many as walk according to this rule, peace be on them, and mercy, and upon the Israel of God.

The term Israelite still refers to God's chosen people, but now in a spiritual rather than physical sense.

Reasonable opinion although the statement "by the time that Revelation was written (after the other scriptures), the racial Jew/Gentile distinction has been fully abandoned" appears unsubstantiated in relation to the question.. The purpose of my question was a hope of some linguistic analysis to substantiate this very matter. Your opinion appears merely a common opinion, unrelated to any hermeneutics. Also, your statement about "John" would not support a case that this John is the same John of the Gospel of John.

@Dhammadhatu says "your statement about "John" would not support a case that this John is the same John of the Gospel of John" — True, but why would anyone be thinking it might?

I have often struggled with your posts & answers. I just needed to clarify it. In the Gospel of John, the word "Jew" is often used in very negative ways, which again is a reason for my asking of the question. The Revelation reads pro-Jewish where as the Gospel of John can read anti-Jewish. My question here revolved around my impression that The Revelation reads as a very primitive form of a new religion that is exclusively about Jewish sectarianism and not yet a non-tribal religion.

Most scholars believe that Paul's letters predate the Book of Revelation. Although some dispute the authenticity of several of these letters, there is near-universal agreement that the following texts are authentic. Estimates given for the dates below should be considered ballpark, as scholars give varying opinions:

Galatians (c. 48 AD)
First Thessalonians (c. 49–51)
First Corinthians (c. 53–54)
Second Corinthians (c. 55–56)
Romans (c. 55–57)
Philippians (c. 57–59 or c. 62)
Philemon (c. 57–59 or c. 62)

With regard to Revelation there are basically two opinions as to its date. Those who date it early put it in the late 60s, in the aftermath of the Neroan persecution. Most scholars date it later, during the persecution of Domitian around 96 c.e. In either case, Revelation would post-date all of the letters of Paul.
Regarding clues, this article should help. One clue to Revelation having an early date is that there is no mention of the destruction of the Temple as one sees in the Gospels. However this is also true of Paul so this fact does not help the OP's general proposition.
Conclusion: Revelation is not "the earliest Christianity." The earliest written records we have from the early Church are the letters of Paul.

Thank you. Personally, as I wrote, I don't find the theories about  Neroan persecution and the persecution of Domitian relevant (although I have read these in Wikipedia). As I wrote, the opening three chapters to me refer to a schism between Jewish sects. The persecution appears similar to persecutions in the Gospels & Acts, which are sectarian.

Revelation is a description of Christ and His body.  7 church section seems to reveal Christ’s body in Gentiles areas outside of Israel proper…which would be a second phase of Christianity, not the earliest phase of “the Way”.
The section of persecution and church horror seems to be a prophecy of things to come.  Since John did not mention AD 70 destruction, Revelation could have been written prior to AD 70, and the persecution prophetic part could be about AD 60-80.
The last section seems to be a Daniel style description of the church and how it was/is formed and what is expected and allowed.
But most importantly, the Revelation is the revelation of Jesus Christ…not all the wild speculation that many find in it. Revelation is a picture of the church overall, as it is based on Christ.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
